# how to grep output from command when there is no pipeline key

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to find status of firewall form Linux box via a console that does not have the pipeline symbol (`|`). how do i grep it without going through lines of output.

This is what i tried:

```
grep firewall < ${systemctl > outfile-firewall}
grep firewall < "$(systemctl > outfile-firewall)"
```

How is the first line command different from the second one? I thought you could actually run a command as a bash script using the file command with curly bracket.

```
grep firewall < $(systemctl)
grep firewall < "$(systemctl)"
```

All the outputs from commands about either give "ambiguous redirect" or "no such file or directory". I know i'm doing something wrong but it should work a good alternative to grepping output via pipeline.

Comment: What console do you have? Why don't you have a pipeline symbol?

Comment: thanks @ KamilCuk. its vmware web console, with only American keyboard style and symbols. The other remote console i could use require installation and i dont  want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try bash process substitution:

```
$ grep firewall <(systemctl)
  ufw.service                            loaded active exited    Uncomplicated firewall
```

[Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: thanks @Zlemini. I got " bash syntax error near unexpected token `(''"

Comment: I am using centos 8, by the way.

Comment: thanks @Zlemini, it worked. I was leaving space between the redirect symbol "<" and the command in the parenthesis "(systemctl)" .

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the pipe symbol in your system you could put the output to a temp file and then grep it from there.

```
systemctl > ctl-output-file

grep firewall ctl-output-file > required-output-file
```

Hope that helps. Have a good day !

Comment: thanks @Tanvir. That's what i ended up doing but I dont want to be creating files everytime i need to grep a commands output. I  prefer the console output command option "grep firewall < $(systemctl)" for example,  but centos 8 is not liking it. I only tried the one liner command  with outfile option to see what i am doing wrong.